# Is there a website that lists the cheapest flights to meet between two cities?

Tags: air-travel, budget, online-resources, fares

My significant other and I currently live on opposite coasts of the United States. We'd like to meet somewhere for the holidays, but we don't really care where; it can be a small town in the middle of nowhere; we like the idea of it being somewhat random :-)

Initially we saw that http://www.skyscanner.com listed flights by ascending price (without having to enter a destination city), so we were going to meet at the first coinciding airport after searching from each of our origin cities. However, we eventually realized that smaller and less popular destinations were all bunched up at the bottom of the list (among the last pages), requiring us to click "Get prices" in order to get prices—so they were not included in the sort.

Does anyone have any recommendations (websites or alternative ideas) for accomplishing what we're trying to do? Thanks in advance!

P.S. We do have strict constraints for the dates of travel; so the website doesn't necessarily have to give us any "grid" or other views for flexible dates. We're interested in flexible *locations* only.

Comment: Thanks! The duplicate was indeed helpful. Sorry I missed it.